# Selective Data Integration in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I am looking to integrate data from one dataframe (A) selectively into another (B). The conditions are as follows: The data frames share two columns (miRNA & Gene). Dataframe A also contains column with a value for the pair.

I want to create a new column in dataframe B that is taken from the Value column in A and contains a value if the pair (same miRNA & Gene from a row in A) matches in B. If a pair does not match in B, create a new row with the score.

Pseudocode

```
#Initialize column in B that will house A value if first two columns match
B$A_Values <- 0

If A[,1:2] == B[,1:2]:
     Change initialized B$A_Value to A[VALUE] of row from A[,1:2]

If A[,1,2] is not in B[,1:2]: 
     Add row in B[,1:2] 
     Change initialized B$A_Value to A[Value] of row from A[,1:2]
```

The dataframes are not of equal length and there will be items in B not found in A, though I assume my initialization will default value them to 0. Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `merge(A, B, by=c("miRNA", "Gene"), all.x=TRUE)`?

Comment: Thank you Khashaa, This is spot on

Comment: Already a deep explanation give here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Thanks Aaghaz!! I didn't find that question in my research on merging. My research focused on selectively merging items based on the content of multiple columns, I did not even think about SQL like statements. This will be a great resource for future data table integration. Cheers, Cody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `merge` function does.

```
AB <- merge(A, B, by = c("miRNA", "Gene"), all = TRUE)
```

or if there are values in `A` that aren't in `B` and you want to remove those values, use

```
AB <- merge(A, B, by = c("miRNA", "Gene"), all.y = TRUE)
```

Comment: Spot on, this solved the issue and answered a follow-up question as well. It seems initializing a column prior will have no effect. It will simply create another column with additions as NAs. Thank you!!